# How to add Both table view and View in a View

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to create a Navigation based application where the rootviewcontroller has a uitableview in it. I would like to change this so its just a standard uiview however everything I have tried so far keeps giving me errors.

First of all you create navigation based application and then delete TableView from rootViewController.xib and take it view from library and connect it and more thing is that to insert uiviewcontroller instead of uitableview in rootviewcontoller.h file and build & run your project its work fine.

How can I add both table view and a uiview to that view?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

1) Go to the .XIB and remove the `UITableView` from the root.
2) Add an `UIView` and put an `UITableView` inside of it.
3) Change the type of controller from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController` ( you can change this on the 3rd tab):

[image]

4) Go to your class and change his parent from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController`.
5) Add the `UITableViewDataSource` and the `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.
6) Connect your `UITableView` data source and delegate to your class from the .XIB